# MySQL database shrinks when uploaded to hosting server. Is there something wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I'm moving my local installation of Magento to a dev location on my hosting server.  FTP is the easy part.
I created a new database on the hosting server, then connected via HeidiSQL.  I exported my database from my local to the hosting server with no problems that I could tell (no errors reported) but I noticed that when I compared the two databases in size, local is 102mb but hosted is 86mb. 
I figured something went wrong, so I dropped all the tables in the hosted mysql to start over.
Second attempt was the same outcome, so I tried a different way. 
I used the Magento backend to make a backup of the database.  Once I had the backup, I did the required modifications - removing the /*!40101 and */ at the beginning and end of the sql file, and uploaded it via PHPMyadmin.

Again, everything seemed to go off without a hitch, but when I accessed the database again via HeidiSQL, same problem, the database on the hosting server is smaller than local.

Am I missing something?  Will this new smaller database still work?

Comment: If everything is working I wouldn't worry about the minor difference in size.

Comment: Whelp!  So far it's not working.  Layout is broken and no navigation.

Comment: I would attempt dumping the DB with the mysql command line interface. Then importing with the CLI as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to both server, I would use mysql dump to back up the database.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction database_name > database_name-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.sql
```

Then FTP the file to the new server

Then run

```
mysql New_DataBase < database_name-xxxxxxx.sql to import
```

You can then rerun the dump to check the sizes.  Use this all the time and works without a hitch.